# Maximum area of the intersection of a parallelogram and a triangle

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, polygons

How large can the intersection of a parallelogram (or a square, if you prefer) with a triangle be, if each of them is of unit area? It is easy to see that the intersection can be of area 3/4 – is this the maximum? (It is not; see Joe's answer below. I now believe $2(\sqrt2−1)≈0.828427$ given by Joe is the correct answer.)

The analogous question can be asked in every dimension greater than 2, replacing parallelogram with parallelepiped (or cube, if you prefer) and triangle with a simplex or an affine square pyramid, each of unit volume.

Comment: I have asked a question about the numerical optimization of your problem on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156677/maximize-area-of-intersecting-triangle-and-square-with-constraints/ You might find it interesting

Comment: Very interesting indeed. Thank you.

Comment: Joe's answer $2(\sqrt{2}-1)$ is indeed the optimal one. In fact, for any triangle with area $1$, one can always find a rectangle of area $1$ so that their intersection has area $2(\sqrt{2}-1)$. For a proof, see my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3389046) to a similar question on math.SE.

Comment: A parallel discussion of this question several years ago on /r/mathriddles: https://www.reddit.com/r/mathriddles/comments/37xj7i/what_is_the_maximum_overlap_area_of_a_square_with/

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if this is the optimal, but an isosceles triangle
with base and height $\sqrt{2}$ overlaps 
$2 \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) \approx 0.828427$
when placed as below,
and so improves over $\frac{3}{4}$:

---

[image: SquareTri]

---

**Added**. A tetrahedron formed from the above triangle
and a point over the center of the cube. Just an image—no computations,
no claims:

---

[image: CubeTetra]

          

<sup>Tetrahedron with same unit-area isosceles base, and height $3$.</sup>

---

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for the answer in the plane, Joe.

Comment: Curiously the unit square has the same overlap $2(\sqrt2-1)$ with an
isosceles right triangle of side $\sqrt{2}$ placed so that
its right angle coincides with one of the square's.

Comment: @Elkies Is it curious? It is not hard to convince oneself that moving the upper edge of the triangle on a horizontal line does not change the overlaping area.

Comment: @coudy But you have to move 2 vertices, not 1. How exactly do you move?

Comment: @Noam D. Elkies: your solution is the other, cut in half

Comment: @Joseph O'Rouke's answer is correct.  You assume the triangle has base along the horizontal axis and is symmetric with respect to the vertical axis, and determined entirely by the location of the horizontal position $(x,0)$ of the corner.  Write an equation for the overlap area, take the derivative with respect to $x$, set it to $0$ and solve for $x$.  If $x=0$ is the center of the square, the solution is $\sqrt{2}/2$--the isosceles triangle.

Comment: @yarchik If you move the tip as well as the base in such a way that the intersections with the vertical sides are unchanged, then the overlapping area does not change. This continuously deforms the one triangle into the other.

Comment: @Joseph O'Rourke: Nice graphics, Joe!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork "Write an equation for the overlap area..." can you be more specific about how you reduce the whole problem to just one parameter? It is clear that $x$ determines the triangle, but what determines the parallelogram? Why do you say "the square"?

Comment: @WlodekKuperberg:  Draw the figure imposing symmetry of the triangle (and of course square).  The unit area constraint means that a *single* parameter (the width of the base of the triangle) determines everything about the problem.  Just look at Joseph O'Rourke's figure!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Without loss of generality you may assume that the parallelogram is a square OR you may assume that the triangle is isosceles or even equilateral, but you CANNOT assume both, let alone that the base of the isosceles triangle is collinear with one side of the square. If you IMPOSE these, you lose generality, which destroys your "proof".

Comment: If the base of the triangle is not parallel to the base of the quadrilateral, rotate the base (keeping its area constant to see that the overlap area cannot decrease.  As such, one can assume the base of the triangle is parallel to the base of the quadrilateral.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  "If the base of the triangle is not parallel to the base of the quadrilateral, rotate the base (keeping its area constant to see that the overlap area cannot decrease." This statement is very ambiguous. I am trying hard to figure out what it is supposed to mean. If your triangle is isosceles, with a very short base but a very long height, then it is certainly better to place the triangle diagonally across the square rather than with its base on the side of the square.

Comment: @WlodekKuperberg:  "rotate the base..." (to be parallel to the edge of the square) and keep the opposite vertex in place.  If possible, then translate the entire triangle to have its base overlap the edge of the square.  In short:  you don't want to place one triangle vertex on an edge and the other outside that edge.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Actually, the example given by Noam D. Elkies (see above), shows that the base of the best isosceles triangle need not be parallel to any of the square's sides, and if you rotate it in any way, the area of the intersection will decrease.  The reference given by yarchik https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156677/maximize-area-of-intersecting-triangle-and-square-with-constraints/ indicates that the maximum should indeed be $2(\sqrt{2} -1)$, but the arguments you give don't look like a proof at all.

Answer (score 3):

(*I posted earlier a false solution which I have removed. Sorry for all this*).

Perhaps the following is safe(?), while I'll prove the critical special case (discussed earlier by participants in this thread):

**CONJECTURE**   Let a triangle and a square, both having area $\ 1,\ $ have one edge of each parallel to the other one. Then the intersection of the square and the triangle has an intersection of maximal area for instance when the said edges are contained in the same straight line and both figures are on the same side of that line and the said edges have the same center and the said triangle has the height equal to $\ \sqrt 2\ $ (*the @JosephO'Rourke example*).

**THEOREM** If we restrict ourselves to the case of an isosceles triangle such that its base and a square edge are contained in the same straight line, and that the centers of the two edges coincide then O'Rourke's example provides the maximal intersection.

Let me start with an elementary lemma:

**Lemma**   Let positive $\ a\ b\in\Bbb R\ $ be such that $\ a\cdot b=\frac 12.\ $ Then
$$ (1-a)^2 + (1-b)^2\ \ge\ 3-2\sqrt 2 $$

**Proof**

$$ (1-a)\cdot(1-b)\ =\ \frac 32 - (a+b)\ \le
   \ \frac 32 - 2\cdot\sqrt{a\cdot b}\ =
       \ \frac 32-\sqrt 2  $$

hence

$$ (1-a)^2 + (1-b)^2\ \ge\ 2\cdot(1-a)\cdot(1-b)
    \ \ge\ 3-2\cdot\sqrt 2 $$
**End of Proof**

**Remark** Our lemma features equality $\ \Leftrightarrow\ a=b=\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}.$

**Proof of the THEOREM**  (I'll keep applying Tales Theorem).

Let the length of the base be $\ 2\cdot x.\ $ When $\ x=1\ $ then we get the OP Wlodek's example with the intersection area $\ \frac 34.\ $ (We already know that it's not optimal).

When $\ x\ge 1\ $ then the area of the intersection is:

$$ 1\ -\ \left(\frac{x-\frac 12}x\right)^2\ =\ \frac 34\ +
      \ \left(\frac 12\right)^2 -\left(\frac{x-\frac 12}x\right)^2 $$

$$ =\,\ \frac 34\ -\ \frac {(x-1)\cdot(3\cdot x-1) } {(2\cdot x)^2}
\,\ \le\,\ \frac 34 $$

for $\ x\ge 1.$ Thus, the situation is not better than for $\ x=1.$

Dually, let's now consider the case of
$\ 0<x\le\frac 12.\ $ Then, the area of the intersection is equal:

$$ 1 - \left(\frac{\frac 1x-1}{\frac 1x}\right)^2
   \ =\ 1-(1-x)^2\ =  $$

$$ \frac 34 - (x-\frac 12)\cdot(x-\frac 32)\,\ \le
     \,\ \frac 34  $$
when $\ 0<x\le\frac 12.$

In the final intermediate case of
$\ \frac 12\le x\le 1,\ $ the area of the intersection is as follows:

$$ 1\ -\ \left(\frac{x-\frac 12}x\right)^2
 \ -\ \left(\frac{\frac 1x-1}{\frac 1x}\right)^2\ = $$

$$ 1\ -\ \left(1-\frac 1{2\cdot x}\right)^2
 \ -\ (1-x)^2\ \le\ 2\cdot(\sqrt 2 - 1) $$

by **lemma**. And by **Remark**, this inequality is actually equality
$\ \Leftrightarrow\ x=\frac 1{\sqrt 2}.$

**End of Proof**

Comment: Dear reader of this *answer*, please make your window wide, so that you can see longer expressions. I could break them by additional lines but that would make the text seem annoyingly *longer*.